# Combination of elements without repetiton of pairs

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Given a set of S elements, how many unique combination of k elements can I find without any ripetition of the same pairs of elements?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics and not directly about programming / coding / software algorithms / programming tools.

Comment: Well you could suggest an algorithmic solution. That is what I am now trying.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of your question is a bit confusing. But I think that perhaps you are looking for something like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240762/all-unique-combinations-of-n-numbers

Edit: Basically, you will have 2^k - 1 unique combinations of elements, given that k is the number of elements in the set.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. The problem is the following. How many k-people tables of poker can I organise without having two people competing more than once? Given S participants.

Comment: I have determined that I am not really confident in my combinatorics enough to give you an answer, but I would recommend you to check out https://math.stackexchange.com for this specific question.